# Dont set value is false in callback before_create in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I Have a Model

```
module Interspire
  class InterspireLead < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :update_contactable

    def update_contactable
      self.contactable = false #contactable datatype is boolean
    end
  end
end
```

But when i create a object.

```
a = Interspire::InterspireLead.create(:email => "abc@gmail.com")
a.valid?
  #=> true
a.errors.full_messages
  #=>[]
a.save
  #=>  ROLLBACK
```

How to fix this erorrs?

Answer (score 1):

Return true in your `update_contactable` method:

```
def update_contactable
  self.contactable = false #contactable datatype is boolean
  true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another callback

```
before_save :update_contactable if: new_record?
```

not

```
before_create
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback needs to be private. (Edit: This is wrong. It is not a requirement!)

An example from the docs:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :record_signup

  private
    def record_signup
      self.signed_up_on = Date.today
    end
end
```

Comment: They don't have to be private! It's not a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - always glad to correct my wrong assumptions! So it's just good practice??

Comment: Yeap. It adds a barrier to accidentally overriding your callback method or letting other know this is internal logic and should not be messed around.

Answer (score 0):

false stops object from being created without any error 
as zhaqiang mentioned:

```
    def update_contactable
    self.contactable = false
    1 == 1
    end
```